# Mostrar imagen de fondo en vista impresión html

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Tengo este código html y css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Recibo</title>
    <style>
      .recibo
      {
       width: 350px;
       height: 500px;
       padding: 5px 4px;
       margin-left: 5px;
       margin-right: 5px;
       background-image: url(recibo.jpg);
       display: inline-block;
      }

      .img_logo
      {
        width: 80px;
        margin: 4px auto 2px;
        display: block;
      }

      .titulo_evento, .p_fecha, .p_hora
      {
        text-align: center;
      }

      .p_fecha
      {
        margin-bottom: 4px;
      }

      .p_hora, .p_persona
      {
        margin-top: 0;
      }

      .p_texto
      {
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-bottom: 8px;
      }

      .span_zona
      {
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-left: 55px;
      }

      .span_fila
      {
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-left: 125px;
      }

      .span_asiento
      {
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-left: 135px;
      }

      .span_zona_info
      {
        margin-left: 41px;
      }

      .span_fila_info
      {
        margin-left: 124px;
      }

      .span_asiento_info
      {
        margin-left: 160px;
      }

      .p_recibo
      {
        float: right;
      }
    </style>
    <style type="text/css" media="print">
        @page{
          margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="recibo">
      <img src="logo.png" class="img_logo">
      <h2 class="titulo_evento">TEATRO CENTRO SAULO GRADUACION GENERACION 2013 - 2019</h2>
      <p class="p_fecha">Viernes 05 Julio 2019</p>
      <p class="p_hora">09:00 hrs.</p>
      <p class="p_texto">RESERVADO POR:</p>
      <p class="p_persona">José Alejandro Alonso Álvarez</p>
      <p class="p_texto">ALUMNO:</p>
      <p class="p_persona">Luis Alberto Alonso Gutiérrez</p>
      <hr>
      <span class="span_zona">ZONA</span><span class="span_fila">FILA</span>
      <span class="span_zona_info">CENTRAL</span><span class="span_fila_info">A</span>
      <span class="span_asiento">ASIENTO</span>
      <span class="span_asiento_info">16</span>
      <p class="p_recibo">No. Recibo: 00001</p>
    </div>
    <script>
      print();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

La pregunta es porque cuando estoy en vista impresión no muestra la imagen de fondo del div??

Comment: Tal vez sea por la configuración del navegador web... en Chrome, por ejemplo, intenta entrando en `Mas opciones` y marcando la casilla `Gráficos de fondo` https://ibb.co/MGJMNKb

Comment: Ya intentaste poner la direccion de carpeta? ejemplo ....imagenes/logo.png?

Comment: También puedes revisar los diferentes tipos de configuración del atributo `style`, uno de ellos para impresora [<style media="print">](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_style_media.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el borrador de CSS **CSS Color Module Level 4** aparece una nueva propiedad llamada [`color-adjust`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color/#color-adjust) la cual te puede ayudar a resolver tu problema.

Por defecto, los user-agent (en este caso los navegadores) tienden a intentar optimizar el resultado para que sea más apropiado al dispositivo de salida (en este caso la impresora) y se ajusten en un principio a lo que el usuario desearía (por ejemplo un background negro podría suponer un gasto innecesario de tinta por lo que a la hora de la impresión lo omiten, por no hablar que con según que tonos de colores podría suponer también una pérdida de calidad).

Con la propiedad `color-adjust: exact` indicas al navegador que te gustaría conservar los colores de la página.

```
* {
   -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; 
   color-adjust: exact;
}
```

Tu ejemplo modificado:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Recibo</title>
    <style>
      * {
          -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; 
          color-adjust: exact;
      }
      
      .recibo
      {
       width: 350px;
       height: 500px;
       padding: 5px 4px;
       margin-left: 5px;
       margin-right: 5px;
       background-image: url(https://i0.wp.com/wptavern.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/stack-overflow.png?ssl=1);
       display: inline-block;
      }

      .img_logo
      {
        width: 80px;
        margin: 4px auto 2px;
        display: block;
      }

      .titulo_evento, .p_fecha, .p_hora
      {
        text-align: center;
      }

      .p_fecha
      {
        margin-bottom: 4px;
      }

      .p_hora, .p_persona
      {
        margin-top: 0;
      }

      .p_texto
      {
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-bottom: 8px;
      }

      .span_zona
      {
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-left: 55px;
      }

      .span_fila
      {
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-left: 125px;
      }

      .span_asiento
      {
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-left: 135px;
      }

      .span_zona_info
      {
        margin-left: 41px;
      }

      .span_fila_info
      {
        margin-left: 124px;
      }

      .span_asiento_info
      {
        margin-left: 160px;
      }

      .p_recibo
      {
        float: right;
      }
    </style>
    <style type="text/css" media="print">
        @page{
          margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="recibo">
      <img src="logo.png" class="img_logo">
      <h2 class="titulo_evento">TEATRO CENTRO SAULO GRADUACION GENERACION 2013 - 2019</h2>
      <p class="p_fecha">Viernes 05 Julio 2019</p>
      <p class="p_hora">09:00 hrs.</p>
      <p class="p_texto">RESERVADO POR:</p>
      <p class="p_persona">José Alejandro Alonso Álvarez</p>
      <p class="p_texto">ALUMNO:</p>
      <p class="p_persona">Luis Alberto Alonso Gutiérrez</p>
      <hr>
      <span class="span_zona">ZONA</span><span class="span_fila">FILA</span>
      <span class="span_zona_info">CENTRAL</span><span class="span_fila_info">A</span>
      <span class="span_asiento">ASIENTO</span>
      <span class="span_asiento_info">16</span>
      <p class="p_recibo">No. Recibo: 00001</p>
    </div>
    <script>
      print();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**IMPORTANTE:** Esta propiedad no está soportada para todos los navegadores. Puedes consultar los navegadores para los que está disponible esta propiedad [aquí](https://caniuse.com/#search=color-adjust).